# C# String replace with dictionary

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, replace

I have a string on which I need to do some replacements. I have a `Dictionary<string, string>` where I have search-replace pairs defined. I have created following extension methods to perform this operation:

```
public static string Replace(this string str, Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);

    return sb.Replace(dict).ToString();
}

public static StringBuild Replace(this StringBuilder sb, 
    Dictionary<string, string> dict)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> replacement in dict)
    {
        sb.Replace(replacement.Key, replacement.Value);
    }

    return sb;
}
```

Is there a better way of doing that?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If the data is tokenized (i.e. "Dear $name$, as of $date$ your balance is $amount$"), then a `Regex` can be useful:

```
static readonly Regex re = new Regex(@"\$(\w+)\$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
static void Main() {
    string input = @"Dear $name$, as of $date$ your balance is $amount$";

    var args = new Dictionary<string, string>(
        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
            {"name", "Mr Smith"},
            {"date", "05 Aug 2009"},
            {"amount", "GBP200"}
        };
    string output = re.Replace(input, match => args[match.Groups[1].Value]);
}
```

However, without something like this, I expect that your `Replace` loop is probably about as much as you can do, without going to extreme lengths. If it isn't tokenized, perhaps profile it; is the `Replace` actually a problem?

Comment: Great answer. I think your proposal will actually be better then iterating over the whole dictionary as the regex will only replace tokens that were found. It won't check for every one that can possibly be inside. So if I have a big dictionary and small number of tokens in the input string that actually can give my app a boost.

Comment: Very useful. I refactored it as an extension method for Regex, which I can't show in a comment so will add as a somewhat redundant extra answer below.

Comment: This will throw an exception if the key is not found.

Comment: Do we have any solution if the key is not found?

Comment: @Phoenix_uy `match => args.TryGetValue(match.Groups[1].Value, out var val) ? val : "*whatever*"`

Answer (score 47):

Do this with Linq:

```
var newstr = dict.Aggregate(str, (current, value) => 
     current.Replace(value.Key, value.Value));
```

**dict** is your search-replace pairs defined Dictionary object.

**str** is your string  which you need to do some replacements with.

Comment: My *hunch*, based on Linq in general, is that this is slightly slower than the foreach. It's also not *that* much shorter ... but I personally love the brevity and find it readable, I just implemented this solution. Thanks.

Comment: No tokenize in my case. Love this one. Thanks Allen. Still usefull 12 years later :D

Answer (score 10):

Seems reasonable to me, except for one thing: it's order-sensitive. For instance, take an input string of "$x $y" and a replacement dictionary of:

```
"$x" => "$y"
"$y" => "foo"
```

The results of the replacement are *either* "foo foo" or "$y foo" depending on which replacement is performed first.

You could control the ordering using a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` instead. The alternative is to walk through the string making sure you don't consume the replacements in further replace operations. That's likely to be a lot harder though.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a lightly re-factored version of @Marc's great answer, to make the functionality available as an extension method to Regex:

```
static void Main() 
{
    string input = @"Dear $name$, as of $date$ your balance is $amount$";
    var args = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    args.Add("name", "Mr Smith");
    args.Add("date", "05 Aug 2009");
    args.Add("amount", "GBP200");

    Regex re = new Regex(@"\$(\w+)\$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
    string output = re.replaceTokens(input, args);

    // spot the LinqPad user // output.Dump();
}

public static class ReplaceTokensUsingDictionary
{
    public static string replaceTokens(this Regex re, string input, IDictionary<string, string> args)
    {
        return re.Replace(input, match => args[match.Groups[1].Value]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when using Marc Gravell's RegEx solution, first check if a token is available using i.e. ContainsKey, this to prevent KeyNotFoundException errors :

```
string output = re.Replace(zpl, match => { return args.ContainsKey(match.Groups[1].Value) ? arg[match.Groups[1].Value] : match.Value; });
```

when using the following slightly modified sample code (1st parameter has different name):

```
    var args = new Dictionary<string, string>(
        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
        {
            {"nameWRONG", "Mr Smith"},
            {"date", "05 Aug 2009"},
            {"AMOUNT", "GBP200"}
        };
```

this produces the following:

"Dear $name$, as of 05 Aug 2009 your balance is GBP200"

Answer (score 2):

The correct tool for this particular task is Mustache, a simple standard logicless templating language.

There are many implementations.  For this example, I'm going to use [stubble](https://github.com/StubbleOrg/Stubble/blob/master/docs/how-to.md):

```cs
var stubble = new StubbleBuilder().Build();
var dataHash = new Dictionary<string, Object>()
{
    {"Foo","My Foo Example"},
    {"Bar",5}
};

var output = stubble.Render(
   "Hey, watch me replace this: {{Foo}} ... with example text.  Also {{bar}} is 5"
   , dataHash
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
public static class StringExm
{
    public static String ReplaceAll(this String str, KeyValuePair<String, String>[] map)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            return str;

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(str.Length);
        StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder(str.Length);
        Int32[] indices = new Int32[map.Length];

        for (Int32 characterIndex = 0; characterIndex < str.Length; characterIndex++)
        {
            Char c = str[characterIndex];
            word.Append(c);

            for (var i = 0; i < map.Length; i++)
            {
                String old = map[i].Key;
                if (word.Length - 1 != indices[i])
                    continue;

                if (old.Length == word.Length && old[word.Length - 1] == c)
                {
                    indices[i] = -old.Length;
                    continue;
                }

                if (old.Length > word.Length && old[word.Length - 1] == c)
                {
                    indices[i]++;
                    continue;
                }

                indices[i] = 0;
            }

            Int32 length = 0, index = -1;
            Boolean exists = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i++)
            {
                if (indices[i] > 0)
                {
                    exists = true;
                    break;
                }

                if (-indices[i] > length)
                {
                    length = -indices[i];
                    index = i;
                }
            }

            if (exists)
                continue;

            if (index >= 0)
            {
                String value = map[index].Value;
                word.Remove(0, length);
                result.Append(value);

                if (word.Length > 0)
                {
                    characterIndex -= word.Length;
                    word.Length = 0;
                }
            }

            result.Append(word);
            word.Length = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i++)
                indices[i] = 0;
        }

        if (word.Length > 0)
            result.Append(word);

        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add some explanation or commentary to your answer, so that readers don't have to closely inspect the code to understand what you are proposing. Especially because this is quite a long snippet, much longer than the other proposed solutions.

Comment: It does what the author wanted to. Unlike an other, it does not use regular expressions, and passes through the line only once, which is important when you need to produce a few tens of replacements.

Comment: This looks like it ignores word boundaries and seems to be very error prone. On the other hand, no explanation is present, so I may be wrong.

Comment: Yeah, there is no check of the word boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check whether such key exists?

- if exists, then remove the pair, otherwise, skip this step;
- add the same key, but now with newly desired value.

  ```
    // say, you have the following collection
    var fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    fields.Add("key1", "value1");
    fields.Add("key2", "value2");
    fields.Add("key3", "value3");

    // now, you want to add a pair "key2"/"value4"
    // or replace current value of "key2" with "value4"
    if (fields.ContainsKey("key2"))
    {
        fields.Remove("key2");
    }
    fields.Add("key2", "value4");
  ```