# How to replace table names with object types in a string?

Tags: c#

In the information system that i am working with (SAP Business One), every document is represented in an SQL table.

```
Client order document : ORDR

Invoice document : OINV

Purchase Quotation : OPRQ
```

when the user clicks on one of the buttons, i need to use a exist function that checks in a part of the SQL tables, and checks if this client has documents in the system.
the function returns a string message with the names of the tables that represent the documents this client has in the system.

i need to write a function that will replace the table names with the documents names.

eample:

```
"Client with ID:5634 has documents: OINV, ORDR"
```

needs to be replace with

```
 "Client with ID:5634 has documents: Invoice, Client order"
```

I guess should use a string dictionary. How to do it?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# String replace with dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231768/c-sharp-string-replace-with-dictionary)

Comment: Does it need to be customizable without recompiling ?

Comment: Do you actually have the text that needs to be replaced, or are you generating "Client with ID:5634 has documents: OINV, ORDR"?

Answer (score 6):

Ideally you shouldn't be doing string replacement with the generated string - instead, generate it from the translated strings. So for example - without knowing what code you've actually got - you could have:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> TableNameTranslations
    = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "ORDR", "Client order document" },
    { "OINV", "Invoice document" },
    { "OPRQ", "Purchase quotation" }
};

...

public string GetClientDocumentDisplayString(int clientId)
{
    var tableNames = GetTableNamesForClient(clientId);
    var translatedNames = tableNames.Select(t => TableNameTranslations[t]);
    return $"Client with ID:{clientId} has documents: {string.Join(",", translatedNames)}";
}

private IList<string> GetTableNamesForClient(int clientId)
{
    // Whatever your code needs, returning ORDR, OINV etc
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a dictionary and Linq:

```
var databases = new Dictionary<string, string>();

databases["OINV"] = "Invoice";
databases["OPRQ"] = "Purchase Quotation";
databases["ORDR"] = "Order";
// ...

var str = "Some random text ORDR more text ORDR text OPRQ text OINV text ORDR";

var newstr = databases.Aggregate(str, (current, value) => 
  current.Replace(value.Key, value.Value));
```

The latter can also be used once you have created your Dictionary:

```
var str2 = new StringBuilder(str);

foreach (var pair in databases) {
    str2.Replace(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}

var newstr = str2.ToString();
```