# Add String into existing String whenever specific characters found

Tags: c#, .net, string

I want to add a specific `String` into an existing `String` whenever the existing `String` contains one of the following characters: `=`, `+`, `-`, `*` or `/`.

For example, I want to add the `String` "*test*" into this existing `String`:
"*=ABC+DEF*"

Resulting `String` should be: "*=testABC+testDEF*"

My first version looks like this and I quess it works but code is ugly

```
string originalFormula;
string newFormula1 = originalFormula.Replace("=", "=test");
string newFormula2 = newFormula1.Replace("+", "+test");
string newFormula3 = newFormula2 .Replace("-", "-test");
string newFormula4 = newFormula3 .Replace("*", "*test");
string newFormula5 = newFormula4 .Replace("/", "/test");
```

Is there some shorter way to achive it ?

Comment: If that works you should use it. You will definitely not find anything shorter, more efficient or more readable.

Comment: Because `Replace` returns the updated string, you could just chain each `Replace` call: `string newFormula = originalFormula.Replace("=", "=test").Replace("+", "+test").Replace("-", "-test").Replace("*", "*test").Replace("/", "/test");` - I don't know if it makes it more readable though.

Comment: Alternatively, this question shows how to use a dictionary of search-replace pairs that might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231768/c-sharp-string-replace-with-dictionary

Comment: @TimSchmelter I will say that it is more readable (lol, semi-irony)... The regex is `"[=+*/-]"`, the replacement is `"$$test"`... See http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%3d%2b*%2f-%5d&i=%3dABC%2bDEF&r=%24%24test .

Comment: What if the string is `"  =  123     + 456"` shall we consider *spaces* or not?

Comment: Yet another question: `"t == --abc"` what is the desired result? `x = -1.2e+123`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP tries to improve working code(it's even unclear why he needs to improve it)

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I feel you are both wrong to claim the code couldn't be made simpler (Philipp's simple use of a regex shows it can be) and wrong to vote to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want your code a bit more elegant, go with Regex.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string originalFormula = ...;
var replacedString = Regex.Replace(myString, "[-+*/=]", "$&test");
```

For better understanding:
`[-+*/=]` groups the charackters you want to check the string for. `$&test` Replaces the found charackter with its match (`$&`) and adds `test` to it.

Answer (score -1):

If your problem is that your code looks ugly maybe you could rewrite it to use a list rather...

```
List<char> characters = new List<char> { '+', '-', '*', '/' };

foreach (var c in characters)
{
    string newValue = String.Format("{0}{1}", c, somethingElse);
    if (originalForumla.Contains(c);
    {
        newForumla = originalFormula.Replace(c, newValue);
    }
}
```